# Javascript Remove Focus on Enter Key Press

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

How can I remove the focus of either input box when I press the "enter" key?

I have this code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { Form, Input, Button, Card } from "antd";

function Login() {
  const [loadings, setloadings] = useState(false);
  const [disabledLoading, setDisabledLoading] = useState(false);

  function changeloading() {
    setloadings(true);
    setDisabledLoading(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setloadings(false);
    }, 1630);
  }

  function passwordEnterPress(e) {
    e.target.blur();
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Card className="home-card">
        <Form>
          <Form.Item name="Username">
            <Input name="username" onPressEnter={passwordEnterPress} />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item name="Password">
            <Input.Password name="password" onPressEnter={passwordEnterPress} />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item>
            <Button
              type="primary"
              htmlType="submit"
              onClick={() => changeloading()}
            >
              Log in
            </Button>
          </Form.Item>
        </Form>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-mendel-hmgop?file=/src/App.js)

**EDIT** per the documentation [link](https://ant.design/components/input/#Input-Methods), there's a `blur` function that I could call to remove the focus, but I don't know how to trigger the function on submit and target the input fields.

If I select either input, it will be focused; however, when I pressed "enter" to submit the form, the focus won't go away. *I want the focus to disappear whenever I press the "enter" key* that submits the form.

It's worth mentioning that I don't want to forcibly overwrite the focus border. I only want the border to disappear whenever I click the login button (which is already working) or press the "enter" key (entire point of this question).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think instead of handling the login with `onClick` of the button. you should handle it in the forms `onSubmit`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

inorder to lose focuse from input when enter key is pressed , you should handle
key up event of input ,as shown below

```
function handleKeyUp(event) {
 //key code for enter
 if (event.keyCode === 13) {
   event.preventDefault();
   event.target.blur();
 }
}
```

now assign this function to on key up event of input box like this

```
<Input name="username" onKeyUp={handleKeyUp} />
```

now to clear focus of input on form submit ,
you can create refernce to both input  as shown below

```
let userNameRef = React.createRef();
let passwordRef = React.createRef();
```

assign this to input as below

```
<Input ref={userNameRef} name="username" onKeyUp={handleKeyUp} />
 <Input.Password ref={passwordRef} name="password" />
```

use these reference to clear focus whenever you want as

```
userNameRef.current.blur();
passwordRef.current.blur();
```

**EDITED**
**What difference does createref on the two fields have compared to using handlekeyup?**

both works the same,
when an event triggered ,event.target is your target element,
while React provide way to access dom element with createRef,
there is no big difference with event.target and ref.current
but its is good to use reference as using reference you can access
element any where, no matter an event is occured or not

Comment: Do I still need "onkeyup" if I created the ref for each field?

Comment: no,onkeyup if for case when you want to lose focus on  enter key press,for example i press enter in username and it should lose focus.

Comment: What difference does `createref` on the two fields have compared to using `handlekeyup`?

Comment: Property 'blur' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.ts(2339)

Comment: you should specify the relevant type for the event in this case or as a workaround you can use any.

Answer (score 1):

In order to call the blur function you would need to get instance of the input tag which you can do by using ref or simply you can call the onPressEnter attribute given by and

```
            <Input.Password name="password" onPressEnter={passwordEnterPress} />
```

then you can write the required functionality like bluring out

```
   function passwordEnterPress(e) {
     e.target.blur()
   }
```

sorry for my poor editing skills below is the code which you can run in your code sandbox. Please note you have to the mouse out of the input box

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { Form, Input, Button, Card } from "antd";

function Login() {
  const [loadings, setloadings] = useState(false);
  const [disabledLoading, setDisabledLoading] = useState(false);
  function changeloading() {
    setloadings(true);
    setDisabledLoading(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setloadings(false);
    }, 1630);
  }

  function passwordEnterPress(e) {
    e.target.blur()
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Card className="home-card">
        <Form>
          <Form.Item name="Username">
            <Input name="username" />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item name="Password">
            <Input.Password name="password" onPressEnter={passwordEnterPress} />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item>
            <Button
              type="primary"
              htmlType="submit"
              onClick={() => changeloading()}
            >
              Log in
            </Button>
          </Form.Item>
        </Form>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: This disables the submit button whenever I press "enter," though

Answer (score 1):

add this in your forms `onSubmit`

```
<Form
  onSubmitCapture={() => {
  if ("activeElement" in document) document.activeElement.blur();
  }}
>
...
</Form>
```

Answer (score 0):

updated answer with form submit. Check the logs in console.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";

import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { Form, Input, Button, Card } from "antd";

function Login() {
  const [loadings, setloadings] = useState(false);
  const [disabledLoading, setDisabledLoading] = useState(false);
  const formRef = useRef()
  function changeloading() {
    setloadings(true);
    setDisabledLoading(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setloadings(false);
    }, 1630);
  }

  function onFinish(values) {
    console.log(values)
  }
  function passwordEnterPress(e) {
    e.target.blur() 
    formRef.current.submit()
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Card className="home-card">
        <Form ref={formRef} onFinish={onFinish}>
          <Form.Item name="Username">
            <Input name="username" />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item name="Password">
            <Input.Password name="password" onPressEnter={passwordEnterPress} />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item>
            <Button
              type="primary"
              htmlType="submit"
              onClick={() => changeloading()}
            >
              Log in
            </Button>
          </Form.Item>
        </Form>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```